# How to fix "No Implementation found method name" in Epson Android SDK?

Tags: android, epson

I want to include Epson library in my android app. Currently upon running on `armeabi-v7a` hardware it fails with aforementioned error.

On Epson Android SDK downloads web page , there are several so files for different architectures, but it's missing `armeabi-v7a`. 
I tried replacing it, just putting so from armeabi folder in my `jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libepos2.so`. And it works ok on dev builds, but as I have to include it as system app, after recovery update it just fails with same error.

I do have this two architectures stated in Application.mk
`APP_ABI :=armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a`

and this one in my build.gradle

```
ndk {
   abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
}
```

I expect *epson printer* to print but it fails with

> No implementation found some epson printer method.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your module:app gradle file

```
ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
        moduleName "libepos2.so"  // 生成so的名称
        ldLibs "log", "z", "m", "jnigraphics", "android"
    }
```